# Put DataView into Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs4, panel, dataview

I created 3 panels: Panel 1, Panel 2 and Panel 3 in Extjs. Please go to the below fiddle link:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1s0l

I also created a DataView with a static store here (fiddle link): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1s0t

Now I wanted to show the above DataView in each of the above panels (Panel 1, Panel 2 and Panel 3). But I am not able to do that. I tried it by giving 'id' to panels and calling that 'id' to show DataView in that panel.

Any approach? How to mege these codes to get that DataView in each Panel?

Thanks!​

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it with calling DataView in panel by 'alias' !! See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1s1q